# What does a GroupBy KeySelector function look like?

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to break the KeySelector function of `GroupBy` into its own method. The KeySelector code isn't right. One major problem is `Widget.foo` isn't matching on "Green" but I think it should be.

**Widget.cs**

```
public class Widget
{
    public string foo { get; set; }
    public double bar { get; set; }
    public bool fee { get; set; }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var widgets = new List<Widget>()
    {
        new Widget() { foo = "red"  , bar = 1.0, fee = true },
        new Widget() { foo = "green", bar = 2.0, fee = true },
        new Widget() { foo = "green", bar = 2.0, fee = false },
        new Widget() { foo = "green", bar = 3.0, fee = false },
        new Widget() { foo = "blue" , bar = 4.0, fee = true }
    };

    var gb = widgets.GroupBy(
        w => GenerateGroupByKey(),
        w => w,
        (prop, groupedWidgets) => new
        {
            GroupedWidgets = groupedWidgets
        }
    ).ToList();
}
```

**KeySelector**

```
static Func<Widget, object> GenerateGroupByKey() 
{
    Func<Widget, object> s = delegate(Widget widget)
    {
        return new { widget.foo };
    };

    return s;
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating an anonymous object to hold the one value that you actually want to group on?

Comment: Because this is an abstraction of a bigger thing Im trying to do

Comment: `w => GenerateGroupByKey()` is wrong, if you're returning a func from a method then it should be just `GenerateGroupByKey()` without the lambda arrow.

Comment: @user875234 If you're actually grouping on multiple values, then you should create an example that does the same.  You also should never use anonymous objects outside of the scope of a single method.  Use a named method if you want to use the object in multiple contexts.

Comment: @Servy In C# 7.3 we can use named value tuples, which is nice.

Comment: @Dai You can already do this in C# 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must pass delegate to parameters, so just call the function and return the delegate.

```
var gb = widgets.GroupBy(
    GenerateGroupByKey(),
    w => w,
    (prop, groupedWidgets) => new
    {
        GroupedWidgets = groupedWidgets
    }
).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Group by you using have parameters like below

```
Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector,
Func<TKey, IEnumerable<TElement>, TResult> resultSelector
```

when you are writing w => GenerateGroupByKey()
you are creating a new FUNC with input parameter as GenerateGroupByKey()

But GenerateGroupByKey() itself is a FUNC

```
static Func<Widget, object> GenerateGroupByKey() 
{
    Func<Widget, object> s = delegate(Widget widget)
    {
        return new { widget.foo };
    };

    return s;
}
```

And you are not invoking that FUNC

Solution:
Do not create another FUNC. Pass GenerateGroupByKey() directly :)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var widgets = new List<Widget>()
    {
        new Widget() { foo = "red"  , bar = 1.0, fee = true },
        new Widget() { foo = "green", bar = 2.0, fee = true },
        new Widget() { foo = "green", bar = 2.0, fee = false },
        new Widget() { foo = "green", bar = 3.0, fee = false },
        new Widget() { foo = "blue" , bar = 4.0, fee = true }
    };

    var gb = widgets.GroupBy(
        GenerateGroupByKey(), // Your FUNC method
        w => w,
        (prop, groupedWidgets) => new
        {
            GroupedWidgets = groupedWidgets
        }
    ).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your grouping does not work because inside `GenerateGroupByKey()` method you create new object.

Objects are equals if they have equal memory references. You can review more details about `Equals` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=netframework-4.7.2).

For what you create new object like `new { widget.foo }`?

You can just return string instead of object.

Try to use delegate like it:

```
static Func<Widget, object> GenerateGroupByKey() 
{
    Func<Widget, object> s = delegate(Widget widget)
    {
        return widget.foo;
    };

    return s;
}
```